# How to select related events from the same table on Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

How do I make the next self query on Elasticsearch?

```
SELECT e.user_id AS user_id,
       e.datetime AS started_at, 
       (SELECT MIN(datetime)  ## taking the closest "end" event datetime of that userId ##
        FROM events 
        WHERE type = "end" AND 
              user_id = e.user_id AND 
              datetime > e.datetime) AS end_at,
       
FROM events AS e
WHERE e.type = "start"
```

Over the next ***event*** data table:

```
{"_id" : "1", "type": "start", "datetime": "2022-02-01T10:15Z", "userId": "1"},
{"_id" : "2", "type": "end", "datetime": "2022-02-01T10:20Z", "userId": "1"},
{"_id" : "3", "type": "start", "datetime": "2022-02-01T10:16Z", "userId": "2"},
{"_id" : "4", "type": "end", "datetime": "2022-02-01T10:21Z", "userId": "2"},
{"_id" : "5", "type": "start", "datetime": "2022-02-02T11:01Z", "userId": "1"},
{"_id" : "6", "type": "end", "datetime": "2022-02-02T11:02Z", "userId": "1"}
```

**The expected result should look like:**

| user_id | started_at | end_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-01T10:15Z | 2022-02-01T10:20Z |
| 2 | 2022-02-01T10:16Z | 2022-02-01T10:21Z |
| 1 | 2022-02-02T11:01Z | 2022-02-02T11:02Z |

Comment: Just curious, why your expected result contains the data of userId 1, it should have for userId 2 as well correct? Also what if user Id 1, more start and end event time, do you want them also ?

Comment: Yes, if there are more events for each user I would like them to be exported and the data of user_id 2 is included as well. I updated my question  @Amit